# Weak solution to PDE boundary value problems

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Take $\lambda>0$ and let $\Delta$ be the Laplacian operator in dimension $n$ and let $\Delta^2:=\Delta\circ\Delta$. Consider the boundary value problem $\Delta^2 u+\lambda u=f$ on some open subset $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth boundary $\partial U$ and boundary conditions $u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}=0$ on $\partial U$. Here $\frac{\partial}{\partial n}$ is the directional derivative in the outward direction normal to $\partial U$. Furthermore $f\in L^2(U)$.

This is part of a more general parabolic PDE boundary/ininital-value problem which I am trying to solve by means of Semi Group theory and Hille-Yosida. Now I was able to find a weak solution $u$ of the above problem in the Sobolev (closed sub)space $H^2_0U)$. In order to make my argument complete I need to show that $u$ is actually also in $H^4$. This is the part I would like to have some support for.

It is a regularity problem. I am using Evans as a reference. But Evans only discusses second order Elliptic PDE's. In which case the typical result he discuses is that given certain conditions it holds that $f\in H^n\Rightarrow u\in H^{n+2}$.

It would be very convenient if these type of results also apply to higher order PD operators such $\Delta^2$. But I am not quite sure how to generalise this to my case.

Comment: Why not applying the elliptic regularity on $v = \Delta u$?

Comment: I have stated the wrong PDE. It should be
$\Delta u + \lambda u =f$.

Comment: @Aris, take a look in THeorem 2.20 and the following corollary: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww1.mate.polimi.it%2F~gazzola%2Fbook_GGS.pdf&ei=D6CaUa7TEaXW0gGfj4GQBw&usg=AFQjCNHj3klgANU088i7mrjbHWCsmuLmUA&sig2=_GoU_IM5Y4TvC6A0u5dWAQ